# Set two environments next to each other

Tags: align, two-column

How would I set two environments next to each other?

Lets say two tables.

I want to have something like this, where red is my page and blue one table and yellow the other. My scenario is that I have a chart on the left side (blue) and a legend on the right (yellow).

[image]

With David's solution:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two tabular environments will go next to each other by default, you need to put a `\par` or other forced line break to stop that. Looks like you want them to align on the bottom so

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{lll}
big table
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[b]{ll}
small table
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Hmm. Could you elaborate on the passed parameters 'lll' and 'll'? For some reason the environment I put in the bottom tabular(small table) is not on the bottom, but rather half of the environment is below the bottom line of the left environment. See my first posting.

Comment: they are the standard tavular column alignments (for 3 left aligned columns and 2 left aligned columns) I just made that up as you did not include a MWE in your question. The [b] makes the baselines of the bottom rows of the two tables line up. Your smaller table clearly has something with the baseline in the middle, don't do that make it have the baseline at the bottom. But since you haven't said what it is I can't really guess.

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it. I had an empty line between `\end{tabular}` and '\begin{tabular}`, which, for some reason, caused the right table to start on a new line.

Comment: As I said in my original answer you need a paragraph separator (which is usually a blank line in TeX) to force tables to be on separate lines. Basically a tabular works just like a big letter. `AB` come next to each other `A blank line B` come in separate paragraphs.